# Throwing Exception on Authentication Failure

Tags: spring-security, exception, spring-boot

I've implemented some token based authentication in my `spring-boot` application. I have a filter and in that filter, I am doing the following:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("X-TOKEN-AUTH");
    String username = null;

    if (securityEnabled) {
       if (authToken != null) {

            try {
                username = userTokenService.validateToken(authToken);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                //TODO log something about signature exception
                log.warn(ae.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I also have a custom AuthFailureHandler:

```
@Component
public class AuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(exception.getMessage());
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

My code `username = userTokenService.validateToken(authToken);` throws an `AuthenticationException` for various reasons. `AuthenticationException` is a custom exception that extends `Exception`. When I catch this exception, I still want to return a 401, but I want my message to appear in what is currently being sent back as JSON by `Spring Security` as default:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1463408604943,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
    "path": "/api/brands/2"
}
```

I would want, for example...

```
{
    "timestamp": 1463408604943,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid Token: Expired",
    "path": "/api/brands/2"
}
```

I'm unsure how to override this behavior.

Comment: This `AuthenticationException` is your custom exception or spring's `AuthenticationException`?

Comment: It is my own custom exception class

Answer (score 1):

So...I finally figured this out. The problem was that Filters are higher up on the food chain so they really don't involve Spring all that much. Where I was throwing an exception in the Filter, Spring wasn't necessarily catching it. The filter would just throw a 500 and display the exception message. To fix it, I simply had to catch my exceptions in the filter and then call `sendError` with the appropriate http status.

```
try {
  username = userTokenService.validateToken(authToken);
  UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
  auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  return;
} catch (Exception ex) {
  httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());
  return;
}
```

The `return` statement in the `catch` is so that my `chain.doFilter(request, response);` at the end of the `doFilter` method isn't called.